# Prevent Registering of Event Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a collection of controls that has a CommandEventhandler registered in a foreach loop:

```
    foreach (Control control in myObject.Controls)
    {
        control.Command += new CommandEventHandler(myEventHandler);
    }
```

Some of the controls in the collection should not have the handler registered.

Is there a way to prevent the Button from having a CommandEventHandler registered?

Comment: Why are you being asked to do this? What code do you have? What have you tried?

Comment: if the event handler method is virtual you could override it and just do nothing. im guessing its a .net base class with an event you want to get rid of, rather than your own code where you can just delete the handler.

Comment: I think you just override or write a wrapper class.  Why is this a mystery?

Comment: How do you know which controls should have the method added and which shouldn't?

Comment: Check out the "is" keyword

Comment: @DavidArno I'm being asked to do this so that some of the buttons don't except the command event handler. I created a custom Button  class with an AllowHandlerRegistration flag. I added an if statement inside the foreach loop to check if the control should allow registration. This works, but seems very clunky if there's  already a way native to Coontrol or Button to accomplish this. It looks like there is not, though. I tried googling with different version of the keywords for this. All hits talked about unsubscribing. None talked of preventing subscription. I then left a question here.

Comment: @Servy We know which ones shouldn't register handlers when they are instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to the code where the event is defined you can put a check in the "add" accessor which would decide whether or not to add the handler.  it'd look something like the following:

```
private EventHandler _myEvent;

public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    add 
    { 
        if (CanAddEventHandler()) // <- that's yours to implement
        {
             _myEvent = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine(_myEvent, value);
        }
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    remove 
    { 
        _myEvent = (EventHandler)Delegate.Remove(_myEvent, value); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You could remove that `Synchronized` and make `_myEvent += value` and `_myEvent -= value`. That is already thread safe isn't it. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is already threadsafe.  The code I provided is based off of the code in Figure 1 in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163533.aspx).  In the article, the author notes that the code in Figure 1 is equivalent to the default event accessor code generated by the compiler

Comment: Not exactly. IIRC then compiler won't take a lock. It takes a low level lock.

Comment: I'm just paraphrasing the article